# iPhone app crashes on startup

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had two apps in xcode, which i wanted to combine, so i started a new project and attempted to put the two apps together in this new one. Was this a really stupid thing to do?

The app now crashes on start up and i have no idea why, i'm 99% the outlets are all connected. It uses xcdatamodel for storage and i've imported the right framework.

Can anyone think of any other things that could be going wrong?

I can attach a zip file with the project in if someone wouldn't mind having a look

Any help is massively appreciated!

Thanks

This is the stack trace:

```
    2010-11-02 08:18:59.903 iStalker[34745:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x5b10e20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key textField.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0256f919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x026bd5de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0256f851 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x0003bc2b _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
    4   Foundation                          0x0003bb99 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    5   UIKit                               0x004b5d0a -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x024e5b6f -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
    7   UIKit                               0x004b4721 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
    8   UIKit                               0x004b64b5 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x002c59bb -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 172
    10  UIKit                               0x002c690d -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 198
    11  UIKit                               0x002d0452 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1958
    12  UIKit                               0x002c9074 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x002cdac4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7495
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x02dd5afa PurpleEventCallback + 1578
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02550dc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x024b1737 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x024ae9c3 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x024ae280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x024ae1a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  UIKit                               0x002c6226 -[UIApplication _run] + 625
    21  UIKit                               0x002d1b58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  iStalker                            0x00001b50 main + 102
    23  iStalker                            0x00001ae1 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x5b11ce0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myTableView.'

Comment: Looks like your XIB file is corrupted.

Comment: what can i do about that? Make a new one??

Comment: Look at the stack trace - what is trying to set what member in your application class? Post the rest of the stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have a text field connected to the application delegate in your main XIB. There is no such field defined on the real application delegate, which is why you’re getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you set main `xib` for app in info plist and set File Owner to `appDelegate`, while main `xib` file's owner is always `UIApplication`. Possible solution - add `Object` to `.xib`, set its class for a`ppDelegate` class and connect all unnecessary outlets. This worked for me.