# Iphone App locks up at splash screen when i perform build

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I have migrated my Iphone app to the 64 bit platform

using xcode the app builds successfully and i am able to create the archive and successfully and it passes itunes validation

Progress !!!

However when i connect my iphone to build and test the app the app opens and loads the splash screen and then locks up

I would appreciate some assistance in interpreting the error code below and advise on what i need to do to remedy the same. As i an relatively new to app development the references in the error message below mean nothing to me

the error message shown in xcode is as follows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x15d56930> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2a46e49f 0x37c24c8b 0x2a46e1a9 0x2b0d4f59 0x2b0e71af 0x2a3be81d 0x2dcee421 0x2dcefd2d 0x2db934eb 0x2db92889 0x2db9d209 0x2db91217 0x30bff0d1 0x2a434d7d 0x2a434041 0x2a4327c3 0x2a3803c1 0x2a3801d3 0x2d9951bf 0x2d98ffa1 0xe86f3 0x381a4aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone app crashes on startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073804/iphone-app-crashes-on-startup)

Comment: `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` is a well known bug issue. Did you do some research about it?

Comment: yes i did i research some of the error code, let me assure you i spend several hours each time i have an error trying to solve it before i concede and then submit a request for assistance

Comment: I have read the suggested similar solution however i cannot understand exactly what steps i need to perform to solve the issue, and assistance to explain the steps i need to perform in more simplistic detailed way would be appreciated

Comment: In one of the xib/storyboard causing the crash, there is a misconnection. You linked "view" to "UIApplication".

Comment: these files were auto generated when i build the cordova project so i did not actually create any of these links hence the reason why i am not even sure where to find thew xib file and what i need to change, basically having had cordova build create the structure i only work with the html files within xcode any of the infrastrucure was auto created by the build I appreciate your assistance and patience if you could direct me to where i find the xib file and what to look for when i open it that needs chaging i would be aternally greatful as will others who read this post in future, at my level